# How To create Responsive Layout

Tags: android-layout

I am new to android and i dont know how to make **responsive layout** which can be
    display equal in all devices,please help me out by providing some code for that.

Comment: Specifically what do you want to have in your layouts would help others to answer your question in a better way.

Comment: @Nitin Sethi : suppose i would like to have 2-3 buttons, 3 edittexts, and setting the height and width with some value, what i need is that when i install the .apk on devices with different resolutions or sizes like 3.2 inch, 4 inch, or 7 inch, the screen should be view same in all devices, it should not be like buttons or edittext may go beyond the screen.

If You or anyone else have that type of real example then plz share it

Comment: Use layout_weight in a LinearLayout and dip units for your widget dimensions. There are loads of examples of using them all over the net.

Answer (score 1):

All android resources are correctly scaled for whatever device you put them on.

However, you may want completely different or just slight different layouts (even though the scaling is handled perfectly) for the purpose of functionality.

For this, you'll need to use the android resource systems constraints and most likely fragments.

Fragments are covered in the following link
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html